# How to choose inputs to an artifial neural network?

Tags: algorithm, ai

I have to implement, as part of an assignment, a learning method that enables minesweepers to avoid colliding with mines. I have been given the choice to choose between a supervised/unsupervised/reinforcement learning algorithm.

I remember in one of my lectures, the lecturer mentioned [ALVIN](http://ftp.utcluj.ro/pub/docs/imaging/Autonomous_driving/Articole%20sortate/CThorpe/ALVINN%20Project%20Home%20Page.htm). He was teaching artificial neural networks.

Since the behaviour I'm looking for is more or less similar to ALVINN's, I want to implement an ANN. I've implemented an ANN before for solving the 3-parity xor problem, here's [my solution](https://github.com/AdeebNqo/mlp_3parityXOR.git). I've never really understood the intuition behind ANNs.

I was wondering, what could the inputs be to my ANN?
In the case of the 3parity xor problem it was obvious.

[EDIT]

The game is not [minesweeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_%28video_game%29). However, it has bots which look like battleships which we refer to as minesweepers. Please see the screenshot below. The goal is for the battleships aka minesweepers to move in one direction each but should learn to avoid mines over time.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inputs are specific to the function of the learning algorithm. You need to analyze the requirements of your assignment to find what inputs are required.

In this case, you want to give your algorithm all the information a the minesweepers have at their disposal.

If each minesweeper has the distance to the nearest mine (but not the direction), then you'll need to use the information provided from multiple minesweepers to attempt to triangulate the position of mines. While avoiding the mines is a good goal, it seems like it should also be important to *find* the mines (they are minesweepers after all). Once a mine position has been triangulated, you can flag it as found and it can be easily avoided.

So, on top of avoiding mines, you should also (in some cases) steer towards mines. The reason you may want to steer towards mines is to help triangulate the position of a mine that's in the area.

For simple avoidance of mines, you can simply detect if you're getting closer to a mine on each iteration. If you're getting closer, turn in a random direction and move forward. Continue until the distance between the minesweeper and mine is increasing.

Comment: Maybe it's too early for brain thinking for me, but what action does the game take if the only input for the network was a single square's count and it's reveal status?  Or are you suggesting the entire map be brought in as input?

Comment: @Byte56, thanx for the response. The game is not minesweeper. It's game with a battletank, which we refer to as the minesweeper. It's basically a vehicle moving in one direction. There are mines in the environment, so the vehicle is supposed to navigate through them, avoiding collisions. Here's a screenshot of the [game](http://snag.gy/LFtZe.jpg). The mines are are green.

Comment: @Adeeb Ah, well that's different then. Before I edit the question to more specifically address your situation. Can you explain more how the game is played? How do the minesweepers traverse the play field? What are the rules? Do the minesweepers take commands? What kind of sensors do they have?

Comment: There is no interaction between game and player. The minesweepers are placed at random points and they have to start moving in a specfic direction. I'm only supposed to implement a learning algorithm such that they can avoid hitting mines.

Comment: OK, but what do the minesweepers know about the world? What do their sensors tell them about the mines?

Comment: They can retrieve the closest Mine. I was thinking of creating an ANN whose only input is the angle between the minesweeper and the mine. My aim is to get angle which it should turn by to avoid hitting the mine. (don't have any ideas. sorta landed on this one)

Comment: Oh, in that case, this is quite literally the simple example commonly used when teaching/learning neural networks, except instead of agents moving towards and eating "food", it's agents avoiding and trying not to intersect "mines".  Inputs would be angle and distance to nearest mine, output is the power behind each tank tread or what-not.  I wouldn't do "input is angle, output is angle", or the solution is less a display of the power of neural nets and more a display of an overcomplicated solution to what could be tankAngle = mineAngle + small variation

Comment: I don't understand how the "power behind each tank tread" could help in changing direction. Mind explaining? (The inputs seem reasonable, thank you very much for that, but I need the output to ensure that the minesweepers avoid the mines).

Comment: If you have two tank treads, putting power to the right one, but not the left will make the tank turn left. Power to the left but not the right will make the tank turn right. I'm not sure you need to get that detailed however.

Comment: Sorry, I admit that was vague.  Think remote control for a toy car, where two sticks drive each side's wheel.  I only mention this as "angle of mine" for input and "angle to turn" for output creates such a simplistic domain that it would only ever require a neural net because the assignment said "use a neural net".  But you can totally do it that way, and it'll work.  You could actually use as inputs the few closest mines if you want a bit more of a sophisticated neural network that makes smarter choices.  The point is that the inputs are the "knowledge of the world" and output is "the choice"

Answer (score 1):

What kind of "simulation" are we talking about? Is this a grid based "board", where each mine and each "minesweeper" is located at a tile of the map? Or do we speak about a continous map, where you have objects and positions.... movements in continous angles (not just 90-degree north, east, south, west...)?

Also: Do the minesweepers have a "goal" (e.g. reach some location on the map)? They actually should have, or they could just stay where they are or move forward-backward (or in a small circle).

If you have a grid based board you can use the relative "view" on the map of you minesweeper as the input. This means one input neuron for each tile location relative to your minesweeper, which is 0 if there is nothing and 1 if there is a mine. Then there should be some input neurons that represent the planed direction. And the output should be the expected result of choosing that direction.

If you have a continuous simulation, you should use the relative distance (x,y) of the nearest mines as an input. So there should be 2 input neurons per mine the minesweeper is aware of. All unused inputs (no more mines in sight) should be set to infinity (huge value). Or you should have a third input neuron for each "mine in sight" slot that is 0 when it's unused or 1 if the other two inputs really point at a mines location. One input should then be the supposed planed angle in which the movement is to be continued.

For both simulation types, two input neurons should be reserved for the -relative- location of the goal which the minesweeper is supposed to reach.

The desired output is then designed to be "high" (1) of the solution is optimal and "low" (0 or -1, depending on activation function) for a bad solution (planed direction leads to problems).

How your desired output looks like depends on the kind learning you are implementing.

1. Observed learning (by giving samples): Generate a lot of random situations. Calculate (or manually choose) your optimal solution. For a grid bases simulation you can use the A* algorithm to find the optimal route to the goal. Then, use the first step in the path as desired output.
2. Unobserved learning: Train your network with reinforcements as: a) how much nearer (good) / farer (bad) it moved to the goal; b) weather it hit a bomb (very negative).

If your algorithm is to be "explorative" (the goal is somewhere, but the minesweeper does not know where), finding a goal should have a positive reinforcement and visiting the same location more than once should have a negative reinforcement.

Also: Think about explaining your problem more detailed. This seems to be a common problem of your questions... Really describe what kind of "rules" exists. For example: If you think it can be done well with Neuronal Networks, but you are free to use any machine learning algorithm you like, state this! What are your minesweepers supposed to do except for avoiding bombs? Else, they can just stay where they are = goal reached. Shall your minesweepers learn by examples given? Or shall they find out by trial and error (just given the result of their actions) = reinforced learned?